# I am not able to send numeric values in sendkeys using selenium

Tags: selenium, sendkeys

i am trying to send a numeric value to a textbox via selenium sendkey method ,which can not update the page.

```
driver.getElementByID('#numtext').sendKeys(123);
```

it gave some error can not send int values..How can i resolve this ..

Comment: -1 for not looking up the method in Seleniums api docs. You are using Seleniums WebElement.sendKeys(CharSequence...) method which requires a CharSequence (for example a String). There is no overloaded sendKeys method that accepts numeric arguments. See [here](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/interactions/Actions.html#sendKeys%28java.lang.CharSequence...%29)

Answer (score 2):

Try to send value using `executeScript` method

```
driver.executeScript("document.getElementById('#numtext').setAttribute('value', 123)");
```

Answer (score 0):

sendKeys takes a string that is entered to the text field. Try:

```
driver.getElementByID('#numtext').sendKeys('123');
```

Comment: sir ...i am using numeric textbox .

Comment: Doesn't that just mean that some validator is checking that the input contains only certain characters? Try entering the numbers one-by-one if the validator is that way picky.

Comment: sir i am using kendoNeumericText box ...i am trying to send values like this can not update...thats my problem

Comment: Did you try sending a string? Just saying "It doesn't work" doesn't help to pin down a resolution.

Comment: sendkeys()--always takes string....how can i send integers...or else how can i send integer value to the numericTextbox..

Comment: Check the browser version and selenium version you are using. Apparently at some point there was a problem with numeric fields and selenium.